# Differential (pushforward) of composite functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be a differentiable map. It is composed of two maps $f:\mathbb{R}^p\to\mathbb{R}^m$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^p$. So $\phi=f\circ g$.

We know by the chain rule, the total derivative $D(f\circ g)=Df\circ Dg$.

My question is what is the differential (pushforward) of $\phi$?

Is it correct that $d\phi=df\circ dg$? If yes, how can we show it?

I am a bit clueless, I find it hard to relate the pushforward with the differential that we learned in elementary calculus. They use the same symbol $d$, are they related? And in what ways are they related? Are they also related with the total derivative $D$?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hint: $d(f\circ g)=\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{\partial (f\circ g)}{\partial x^i}dx^i$ then apply the chain rule.